# Uncaught exception 'PDOException'

Tags: magento-1.8, product, php

I have a script that allows me to add a sample request button to my product pages, I have a script called getSample.php but when I click on the sample button on the product page I'm taken to getSample.php which is showing this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or
>   update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`japecilot_mage2`.`mage_catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_OZSS_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_OZSS_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `mage_eav_attribute_set)'
>   in
>   /var/www/vhosts/webcontrolcentre.co.uk/httpdocs/perfume/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/vhosts/webcontrolcentre.co.uk/httpdocs/perfume/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228):
>   PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1
>   /var/www/vhosts/webcontrolcentre.co.uk/httpdocs/perfume/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110):
>   Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) #2
>   /var/www/vhosts/webcontrolcentre.co.uk/httpdocs/perfume/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291):
>   Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) #3
>   /var/www/vhosts/webcontrolcentre.co.uk/httpdocs/perfume/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479):
>   Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) #4 /var/w in
>   /var/www/vhosts/webcontrolcentre.co.uk/httpdocs/perfume/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php
>   on line 234

the code in the getSample.php is:

```
<?php

 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 //print_r($_POST);

 require_once 'app/Mage.php';
 Mage::app();



 Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));
 Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setSampleError("");
 // Store users session
 $session = Mage::getSingleton("customer/session");

 //Store cart items
 $totalNumOfCartItem = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getItemsQty();

 //Store cart items
 $theitems = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getItems();

 $thecount = 0;

 foreach($theitems as $ti){

 $thename = $ti['name'];

 $test = strpos($thename,'Free Sample');

 if($test !== false){
 $thecount = $thecount+1;
 }

 }

 if(isset($_POST['name'])){
 $name = $_POST['name'];

 $id = $_POST['id'];
 if(isset($_POST['simpleid']) && !empty($_POST['simpleid'])){
 $simpleid = $_POST['simpleid'];
 }
 }
 if(isset($_GET['name'])){
 $name = $_GET['name'];
 if(isset($_GET['simpleid']) && !empty($_GET['simpleid'])){
 $simpleid = $_GET['simpleid'];
 }
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 }

 // retrict shopping cart to only allow 5 samples
 if ($totalNumOfCartItem <= 4)
 {
 $theproduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);

 if($simpleid){
 $thesimple = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($simpleid);
 }

 if($thecount < 2)
 {
 // instatiate Product
 $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
 if($simpleid){
 $product->setSku($thesimple->getSku()."*".rand());
 } else {
 $product->setSku($theproduct->getSku()."*".rand());
 }
 $product->setName("Sample of ".$name);
 // $product->setDescription("Sample of ".$name);
 $product->setShortDescription($name." – Sample");
 $product->setPrice(0.00);
 $product->setTypeId('simple');

 $product->setImageUrl($theproduct->getImageUrl()); // set the images from the original product
 $product->setThumbnailUrl($theproduct->getImageUrl());
 $product->setImage($theproduct->getSmallImage());
 $product->setMediaGallery (array('images'=>array (), 'values'=>array ()));
 $product->addImageToMediaGallery(Mage::getBaseDir('media')."/catalog/product".$theproduct->getSmallImage(), array('image','small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
 $product->setAttributeSetId("9"); // need to look this up
 $product->setCategoryIds("3"); // need to look these up
 $product->setWeight(21212121.21);
 $product->setTaxClassId(2); // taxable goods
 $product->setVisibility(1); // catalog, search
 $product->setStatus(1); // enabled
 // assign product to the default website
 $product->setWebsiteIds(array(Mage::app()->getStore(true)->getWebsite()->getId()));


 // get product’s general info such price, status, description

 $stockData = $product->getStockData();

 // update stock data using new data
 $stockData['qty'] = 1;
 $stockData['is_in_stock'] = 1;
 $stockData['manage_stock'] = 1;
 $stockData['max_sale_qty'] = 5;

 // then set product’s stock data to update
 $product->setStockData($stockData);
 //die();

 // call save() method to save your product with updated data
 $product->save();


 header("Location: /checkout/cart/add/product/".$product->getId()."/");
 }
 }

 else
 {
 Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->addError("You are only allowed a maximum of 5 sample products");

 header("Location: /checkout/cart");
 }
 ?>
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message looks like your product is referencing an attribute_set_id which is not present in the database.

Take a look into your database into the table `mage_catalog_product_entity`, find your product and look for the column `attribute_set_id`. The number in there e.g. 4 should be present in the table `mage_eav_attribute_set` in the id column. If not, your product uses an attribute set which is not available any more.

This page kind of explains what attribute sets are: http://inchoo.net/magento/importance-of-planning-attribute-sets/

One remark: Your code totally works around the framework, there might even be some security issues. (using POST, header()). You're also updating stock data. Magento does that when the customer actually finishes the checkout process, there's no need to do it manually.

Comment: Thankyou for your comment, I have the attribute_set_id of 4 in my database which is also present as an ID in the mage_eav_attribute_set table.

Comment: Your code sets the attributeSetId to 9. Check your mage_eav_attribute_set table and figure our which attribute set is used for products. You can do that by looking for the entity_type catalog_product in mage_eav_entity_type. Get the entity_type_id from there and compare it to mage_eav_attribute_set.

$product->setAttributeSetId("9"); // need to look this up

Comment: Thankyou for your help, that has now solved the errors.